# Cast player sample uses extension to determine if the stream is a live stream, can it use headers?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have an m3u8 stream that doesn't have the m3u8 extension on the file and it fails to play. If I change the extension then it works. I think it is because of this on `player.js` from the CastPlayer example on github.

```
if (sampleplayer.getExtension_(path) === 'm3u8' ||
        type === 'application/x-mpegurl' ||
        type === 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl') {
        return cast.player.api.CreateHlsStreamingProtocol;
    } else if (sampleplayer.getExtension_(path) === 'mpd' ||
        type === 'application/dash+xml') {
        return cast.player.api.CreateDashStreamingProtocol;
    } else if (path.indexOf('.ism') > -1 ||
        type === 'application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml') {
        return cast.player.api.CreateSmoothStreamingProtocol;
    }
```

Since my headers are ok, would it be possible to use the headers instead of the extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not completely understanding your question but since you are using a custom receiver, feel free to make changes as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#demonstration-code):

> {...} This code currently implements a trivial parser to figure out the
>   content type based on the extension of the file. It is for example
>   only; you should implement your own mechanism to do this.

I assume that means that if you're able to determine the stream type some other way, go for it.